# Remove small circle in big circle opencv android

Tags: android, opencv

I am a newbie android and opencv. I have some problem when i try to remove some small circle inside big circle (I just want to have 1 big circle). [image]

My big circle is a ball and some small circle is reflect of light when i put ball near camera. I was try to use morphology to remove small circle but when i move ball far away, circle is smaller and it is removed too, I don't know how to solve this problem.

Answer (score -1):

Use findContours function ifrom OpenCV : http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html?highlight=findcontours#findcontours
If you use CV_RETR_EXTERNAL option, it will give your only the extreme outer contour.

Comment: If you actually try it, you'll see that it won't work in this case.

Comment: Yes i used CV_RETR_EXTERNAL option but no thing happen, It seem to be receive small circle inside big circle